# Codename One: How can I scale an image to fit width of screen?

Tags: image, list, width, listitem, codenameone

Good evening,

I'm using Eclipse with the UI-Framework Codename One.

I would like to know how it would be possible to scale an image to fit the width of the screen?
I would like to create a list with one image( or even an imageslider if this is possible), which has the full width of the phone, and under that some text.

Another question is, how can I set an Image via Hastable and Vector from code ? I tried everything but I can't find a solution.

Thank you a lot,

Greetings Patric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

Normally you would just set the image as the background image of the component and select the background behavior as SCALE_TO_FIT which can be done both via the theme designer and via the `Style` object of the component.

You can also use the ImageViewer class if you want to have a viewable/zoomable image.

You can also just scale the image to the size you want using either the `scaled()` method or `ImageIO`.

Comment: Thank you for your unbelievable fast answer!
I'm new to codename one, and I have some problems understanding how to start coding here. I'm Android Developer for 2 Years now. Is there any example code out there ? Maybe one with Designer and one without?

I already watched all the How Do I? Videos, they are very informative and not hard to understand but from them I dont get how to go on.

Comment: I'm not able to find a background behavior property, on the label nor on the List.

Comment: Use getUnselectedStyle()/getSelectedStyle() they are there for every Component in Codename One.

Comment: I have no Idea why I'm stock like that, but again I can't find anything in the Designer Selected/UnselectedStyle, and i don't get from the documentation where to start doing it via code. 
I tried to create tabs via code, and it seems buggy too. I don't know what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: You can select the Events tab and click Before Show to write code. 

You can customize these things visually in the theme section by setting the UIID property and adding a theme entry: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html